# Jama - Matrix must be square exception while finding determinant

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, jama, determinants

I am new to using Jama for matrices. My problem is while I'm using `det()` method (which is related with `LUDecomposition` class) it gives `"Matrix must be square"`. Ok my matrix is triangle but with `LUDecomposition` it should give me square matrix. My code like this

```
public double findDeterminant(Matrix mtrx) {
    LUDecomposition dec = new LUDecomposition(mtrx);        
    det = dec.det();
    return det;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/) of `LUDecomposition`:

> For an *m-by-n* matrix `A` with *m >= n*, the LU decomposition is an *m-by-n* unit lower triangular matrix `L`, an *n-by-n* upper triangular matrix `U`, and a permutation vector `pig` of length *m* so that `A(piv,:) = L*U`. If *m < n*, then `L` is *m-by-m* and `U` is *m-by-n*.

Did you perhaps mean to find the determinant of `getU()` or `getL()` (*one* of which will be square, based on the description above)?

The `det` method of `LUDecomposition` returns the determinant of *the matrix that was used to construct the object* (in your case `mtrx`, which I'm assuming isn't square).

Comment: @sinanselimoglu You will probably have to check the dimensions of `mtrx` to determine if `L` is square or if `U` is square.

Comment: @sinanselimoglu Not sure what else I can do... I mean I basically gave you the answer on a silver platter.